# How to force Mono to display line numbers in stack trace

Tags: c#, mono

When I ask Mono for a stack trace, it displays a random hex code rather than the actual filename and line number. How do I *force* Mono to tell me the real line number?

Everything on the Internet claims that if you just run Mono with the `--debug` switch, it will magically start working. It *does not* work!

My process:

- Compile code in Visual Studio, in Debug mode.
- Copy contents of `bin\Debug` folder to Linux PC.
- Run `mono --debug Program.exe`
- Observe blatant lack of line numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MONO_DEBUG=no-compact-seq-points mono --debug yourApp.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Try manually renaming all `<DebugType>full</DebugType>` occurrences in your **csproj** file to `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>`

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid did this help you? or did you find a different solution?